# How to specify artifact name in maven that I want installed/deployed

Tags: java, maven, deployment, packaging

I have a maven pom orchestrator file used to control the build of all my modules.  As a final build in my orchestrator step, I am calling a shell script via the exec-maven-plugin to manually create a zip file.

I would like to put this zip file that I have created in my m2 folder and deployed to my nexus repo.

Is there a simple of indicating to maven to deploy/install this zip file?  Right now my packaging type for my file is pom, but I can change that to be something else.

Changing the build to use a plugin and not the shell script is not an option at this time.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Proj</name>

    <modules>
        <module>ProjCommon</module>
        <module>ProjEar</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Zip packaging and deployment</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${bash.path}</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>${bash.arguments}</argument>
                                <argument>${basedir}/../deployer/post-build-sbic.sh</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <MAJOR_VERSION>${major.version}</MAJOR_VERSION>
                                <MINOR_VERSION>${minor.version}</MINOR_VERSION>
                                <ARTIFACTS_DIR>${artifacts.folder}</ARTIFACTS_DIR>
                            </environmentVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>attach-artifacts</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                  <artifact>
                      <file>target/my-custom-archive.zip</file>
                      <type>zip</type>
                      <classifier>dist</classifier>
                  </artifact>
              </artifacts>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That's great - just the type of thing I was looking for.  Do you know of any way that I can modify the artifactId/groupId for the zip file, or the best I can do is to use the classifer?

Comment: Don't think so. That would be like having children and let them live with your neighbour.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks for letting me know about this plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Try to perform {mvn deploy} on your project. This should build your project and deploy the artifact to your repo and nexus if everything succeeded.

Comment: That will only deploy the pom.  Not my zip that I have built manually via my script.